# Definition of the Fell topology: Completion with respect to a seminorm

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, representation-theory, topological-groups

I'm reading about the Fell topology and have a question on some preliminary material.  My reference is [these](https://services.math.duke.edu/~hahn/Chapter3.pdf) notes on automorphic representations.  Let $G$ be a locally compact Hausdorff, second countable unimodular group with Haar measure $dg$.  Let $(\pi,V)$ be a Hilbert space representation of $G$, continuous in the sense that for every $v \in V$, the map $g \mapsto \pi(g)v$ is continuous $G \rightarrow V$, where $V$ is given the norm topology.

For each $f \in L^1(G)$, we have a bounded linear operator $\pi(f)$ on $V$ given by $\pi(f)v = \int\limits_G f(g)\pi(g)v\space dg$.  This makes sense as a vector valued integral.  The operator norm $|| \pi(f)||$ is bounded by the $L^1$ norm $||f||_1$.

Let $\hat{G}$ be the unitary dual of $G$, the set of equivalence classes of irreducible unitary Hilbert space representations of $G$.  For $f \in L^1(G)$, we define a *seminorm* by

$$||f||_{\ast} = \sup\limits_{\pi \in \hat{G}} ||\pi(f)||$$

The **C-$\ast$ algebra of $G$** is defined to be the completion of $L^1(G)$ with respect to this seminorm.

What is meant by the completion of a vector space with respect to a seminorm?  What are some good references on this topic?

Comment: Completeness makes sense for arbitrary metric spaces. A seminorm induces a metric.

Comment: They don't induce a metric, right?  We are missing the property that $d(x,y) = 0$ implies $x= y$.

Comment: Every topological vector space has a canonical notion of completeness: A net $\langle x_\alpha\rangle$ is Cauchy if for every symmetric neighborhood $U$ of $0$, there exists an index $\gamma$ such that $x_\lambda-x_\beta\in U$ for $\lambda,\beta\geq\gamma$.

Comment: So there is a notion of completeness.  Is there a notion of completion?

Comment: In any case, I just found out Corollary 7.2 of Folland's book *A Course in Abstract Harmonic Analysis* shows that $||f||_{\ast}$ is actually a norm

Answer (score 2):

Even without knowing that $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ is a norm, one can define the completion of $L^1(G)$ w.r.t. $\Vert \cdot \Vert$:

For any first-countable topological group, one can define its completion, using Cauchy-sequences.